# Multiple validation on one attribute in Yii

Tags: validation, yii

I want to validate an attribute on multiple CValidator classes.

To be more specific, I want an email address to be validated by the email validator, but I also want it to be required.

I can of course define two separate rules, like so:

```
array('email', 'email'),
array('email', 'required'),
```

But when I leave the input blank the validation only returns an error saying the field is required, but it doesn't return an error saying it has to be an email address. When I fill in a non-email string, it then returns the email validation error.

I tried to combine the validators in an array, and a comma separated string but that doesn't work. So I guess the only option is to use a custom validation method.

But how can I use the built-in `CValidator` validators in this method? And how can I build it, that the two rules are validated together at once instead of one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting you right you have an issue with error message. I think you can use following approach to show message.

```
array('email', 'email', 'message' => 'Please provide valid email.'),
array('email', 'required', 'message' => 'Email is required. Please provide valid email.'),
```

Hope this will help you....

Answer (score 1):

User interface wise this makes little sense to specify that an email is invalid when left empty. You tell them that the email is required when empty or invalid when it isn't empty but not an email. Doing both seems very confusing to me.

I personally just use:

```
array('email', 'email', 'allowEmpty' => FALSE),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the errorsummary() method:

EDIT:
Changed reference to CHTML

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#errorSummary-detail

In your view, add

```
<?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($model, NULL, NULL, array ('firstError' => false));
      ...
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
</div>
```

From the documentation

> additional HTML attributes to be rendered in the container div tag. A
>   special option named 'firstError' is recognized, which when set true,
>   will make the error summary to show only the first error message of
>   each attribute. If this is not set or is false, all error messages
>   will be displayed. This option has been available since version 1.1.3.

Note that if you are using Ajax validation then you will get the first error only, next to the fields

Comment: I'am already using this method, but it only gives me the first error message of the attribute, and - of course - the error messages of the other attributes. And not, and thats what I want, multiple error messages for a single attribute, besides the error messages of the other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually model validation returns all errors of validation, but `CActiveForm::error` method shows only first one for selected attribute. I guess you use now something like this:

```
<?php echo $form->error($model,'attr'); ?>
```

but instead should use

```
<?php if ($model->hasErrors('attr')) : ?>
    <?php $errorList = $model->getErrors('attr'); ?>
    <?php foreach ($errorList as $error) : ?>
        // display error
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Also you can write your own helper method for displaying all errors for single attribute.

Comment: `$model->hasErrors('attr')` returns an boolean right? So, i cant loop through it...

Comment: Right. Edited my answer.

Comment: This doesn't work. There is still only one error returned, so i guess the validating process stops if one rule returns false.

Comment: Validators do not return false or true, they add errors to your model. Look at validate() method of CModel class.

Comment: Besides if you look at CEmailValidator you will notice that there is allowEmpty property that is true by default. You should change it to false in your rules array: array('email', 'email', 'allowEmpty'=>false),

Comment: Thanks, that did help. But just in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skipOnError` property of the validator.

```
array('email', 'email', 'skipOnError' => false),
array('email', 'required', 'skipOnError' => false),
```